# How can I teleport with an unwilling creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, teleportation

It will happen sometimes that my party has captured and subdued a bad guy that we don't wish to kill (but do want to keep with us for interrogation or etc purposes). The bad guys are generally very unhappy and want to escape. If we're in the middle of the wilderness/a sinking ship/the wrong city/far away from the antimagic field/etc, it would be very nice to use some sort of teleportation spell or series of spells to get the whole group (including the bad guy) away to wherever we want to go.

However, all of the 5e spells for moving people in space I've found have specified a willing creature. Is there any way my party can take our captured baddie with us, other than tying them up and hauling them away by hand?

The further distance we're able to move with the unwilling creature, the better.

Comment: Is *making* the baddie into a willing creature an option? Such as what is discussed here: "[Can you make an unwilling creature willing? In other words, what defines “willing”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62794)" Or are you primarily interested in answers that don't involve that route?

Comment: Is knocking out the unwilling creature and carrying their unconscious body a option, or does this need to be done while the creature is conscious (and therefore definitely unwilling)?

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Probably not: [Can unconscious characters be unwilling?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143148), [Can unconscious characters be willing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80393)

Comment: If the alternative is being left behind tied up securely without access to food or water, won't they likely be willing anyway? Assuming you're not in a place where their allies could find and aid them.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Kill them, teleport them, then revivify them.

The rules suggest that a corpse is not a creature, rather is an object. This is explored in detail in this Q&A: [Is a dead creature's body considered an "object"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55951/62294)

Assuming this, if you have access to the spell *revivify*, you could kill the hostage, then teleport the party by whatever usual means you have that doesn’t allow unwilling creatures, and then cast *revivify* or whatever resurrection spell suits your fancy upon arrival.

It should be noted however, that the *Dungeon Master's Guide* has this general rule concering resurrection magic:

> A soul can’t be returned to life if it doesn’t wish to be. A soul knows the name, alignment, and patron deity (if any) of the character attempting to revive it and might refuse to return on that basis. For example, if the honorable knight Sturm Brightblade is slain and a high priestess of Takhisis (god of evil dragons) grabs his body, Sturm might not wish to be raised from the dead by her. Any attempts she makes to revive him automatically fail. If the evil cleric wants to revive Sturm to interrogate him, she needs to find some way to trick his soul, such as duping a good cleric into raising him and then capturing him once he is alive again.

So it will be up to the DM if the hostage's soul is willing to return. Maybe if you're nice to them and have promised them freedom later, and they believe you, they'll come back.

You can also use *gentle repose* to extend the time during which *revivify* will still work:

> You touch a corpse or other remains. For the duration, the target is protected from decay and can't become undead.
>
> The spell also effectively extends the time limit on raising the target from the dead, since days spent under the influence of this spell don't count against the time limit of spells such as raise dead.

So kill your guy, cast *gentle repose*, and you've got a week and a half to *revivify* him. Just be careful not to attract too much attention to yourself, people might be suspicious if you're carrying a dead guy.

[image: Weekend at Bernie's]

#### *Teleportation circle*

The 5th level spell *teleportation circle* let's you drag them through:

> Any creature that enters the portal instantly appears within 5 feet of the destination circle or in the nearest unoccupied space if that space is occupied.

#### *Gate*

*Gate* is a 9th level spell that creates a portal to a other plane:

> You conjure a portal linking an unoccupied space you can see within range to a precise location on a different plane of existence. The portal is a circular opening, which you can make 5 to 20 feet in diameter. You can orient the portal in any direction you choose. The portal lasts for the duration.

Open your gate and carry your hostage through.

#### *Transport via plants*

*Transport via plants* is a 6th level Druid spell:

> This spell creates a magical link between a Large or larger inanimate plant within range and another plant, at any distance, on the same plane of existence. You must have seen or touched the destination plant at least once before. For the duration, any creature can step into the target plant and exit from the destination plant by using 5 feet of movement.

For this one, it isn’t abundantly clear how it works with an unwilling creature forced into the plant, so you may need a bit of DM generosity for this one.

#### Make them willing.

I won't get too much into the details here, but there are a number of ways an unwilling creature can be made into a willing creature, as discussed in this Q&A: [Can you make an unwilling creature willing? In other words, what defines “willing”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62794/62294)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Great idea.

Comment: *cackle* Weekend at Bernies addendum is appreciated

Comment: Adventure title: "Weekend at BBEG's"

Comment: One important caveat to this strategy is that the Dungeon Master's Guide contains a general rule against reviving unwilling characters: *"A soul can't be returned to life if it doesn't wish to be."* [**Bringing Back the Dead**, DMG, pg. 24]. Whether or not rules provided in DMG are actually followed is at the discretion of the DM (i.e. they're all technically optional rules) but a player attempting to do this at their table should probably double-check with the DM first.

Comment: @Xirema Ah, good point, I'll mention that.

Comment: Also, not really related to RAW which this addresses but the RP after you kill someone gets *interesting* to say the least... not to mention in some games making death meaningless to some extent.

Comment: @Xirema *Revivify* does not require a willing soul the way that a *raise dead* or a *resurrection* spell does

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: Good point. And it works with the flavor of the spell (it's basically magic CPR for someone who is only *mostly* dead, Princess Bride-style, pulling 'em back before they enter the light). So assuming you're willing to blow 300 GP, and either use *gentle repose* to keep them fresh, or revive them *really* quickly to stay within the one minute time limit, it's a practical solution.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It's not clear if the DMG rule on resurrection applies to revivify. Up to the DM, I'd imagine.

Comment: If *revivify* required a willing soul, the spell would say so - there are no secret rules.   (I could barely keep a straight face as I typed that)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Okay, but I quoted a rule that seems like it applies to *revivify*, so it's not exactly a secret.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: Good question whether that DMG paragraph was intended to apply to *all* forms including revivify, or if it was intended to expand upon the raise-dead / resurrection type spells that already briefly mention that requirement.  So yes you could rule either way, and this general area is prime territory for GMs to choose how magic works in their world.  (e.g. Matt Mercer's group ability check to avoid the revolving door pearly gates problem, which he applies to resurrections other than revivify, narratively the soul hasn't gone yet.  Gentle Repose + reviv hasn't come up on CR...)

Comment: @PeterCordes Doesn’t Matt give one freebie on resurrection? Or does he have them roll even from the first attempt?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: Even a character's first requires the same check.  The DC gets higher for repeated deaths, starting at DC10 so with successful help by others it's quite likely (but still not guaranteed).  https://criticalrole.fandom.com/wiki/Resurrection has the rules used on Critical Role; I think that looks right.  But sometimes he's let Revivify work in combat with no check at all, other times (out of combat) as described in the link, failure on the roll means you can try again with up to 3 people helping in the raise dead ritual to lower the DC.

Comment: I am away from my books, but wouldn't making them unconscious be just as effective?

Comment: @JoelHarmon An unconscious creature cannot be willing. We’ve two Q&As on it somewhere, just search “unconscious willing”

Answer (score 21):

### Put them into a bag of holding

The rules on a target being willing for the teleport spell aren't relevant if the target has been placed into a bag of holding as you are teleporting the bag, not your enemy. Said enemy stays within the extradimensional space of the bag during the teleport so they aren't technically being moved by the spell.

Comment: Just keep an eye on the clock, you don't want them to run out of air inside the bag...

Comment: @TobiasF. I figured they'd force the person into the bag, teleport, then dump them straight back out. Then again, some players/characters can be good examples of ADD.

Comment: Make sure to confiscate sharp objects and hog-tie them or knock them out: *If the bag is **overloaded, pierced, or torn** it ruptures and is destroyed, and its contents are scattered in the Astral Plane* https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Bag%20of%20Holding.  An enemy who doesn't know the consequences of tearing the bag from the inside might go for it, so might someone who could handle themselves on the Astral Plane, or one who's just bloody-minded enough to spite you and damage your property. (Or thinks it will gate the party - it won't, that's bag inside bag, this is just contents)

Comment: @PeterCordes I've never been sure - can you actually damage the bag in that fashion from the inside? I've always figured it has to be done from the outside, otherwise you'd run the risk of damaging the bag just by putting sharp objects inside of it.

Comment: I assumed you did need to be careful with a Bag of Holding, e.g. putting sharp things in their scabbards or otherwise protecting the bag from them, just like when putting them into normal bags. (Except they would only have their own weight, not jostling, or compressing forces like you would from carrying around a normal bag.)  [Sharp objects in a Bag of Holding](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103564) says pathfinder 1e BoH can be pierced from the inside.  Seems like rpg.SE could use a 5e version of that question (I didn't search for discussion else)

Comment: [Can I push an enemy into a bag of holding?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164855) asks if they can destroy it from inside, but that part wasn't answered.  [Can a portable hole be used on a shield?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79476) points out that portable holes don't have weaknesses from the inside.

Answer (score 11):

Options include:

- [*teleportation circle*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleportation-circle) - You just have to drag them through. Destination can be any circle on the plane you know about so could be very far indeed.
- [*arcane gate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcane-gate) You just have to drag them through. The destination isn't terribly far away.
- [*transport via plants*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/transport-via-plants) You just have to drag them through. Arguably might not work depending on DM's reading of "use 5ft of movement", as it could be interpreted that the creature has to use their movement. Distance depends on how far the tree in question is.
- [*banishment*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) You can use a high enough spell slot to banish the whole party and the enemy. There is less control about where you land and potential of ending up at different locations if anyone is from another plane. Distance is arguably greatest here, as you'll go to another plane entirely.
- [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)
- Cleric using Divine Intervention and rolling less than their class level on a percentile dice. I know it isn't likely, but thought it worth mentioning for completeness.
- You can make them willing using [*suggestion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/suggestion), or *[charm person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person)* or [friends](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/friends) and high persuasion check, or [true polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) them into an object, or temporarily kill them to be an object. Then use any one of the following:

  - [*teleport*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleport)
  - [*dimension door*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) If it is just you and them, and only if they are medium or smaller, shorter distance.
  - [*plane shift*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/plane-shift) Would be again planer travel.
  - [*gate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gate) Again planer travel, but this is mighty spell and high cost.
  - [*astral projection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/astral-projection) But you'd be vulnerable for some time getting them a color pool. Potentially planar travel, but destination might be on the prime material plane.

Comment: I'm not *entirely* sure *transport via plants* would work considering that it says "any creature can step into the target plant and exit from the destination plant by using 5 feet of movement."

Comment: That is a sticky point, but I think the *intent* is that the tunnel is 5ft, not that it has to use movement specifically.... I'll add a disclaimer to that one.

Comment: *Teleportation Circle* is definitely the most straightforward, but you'd better be prepared to explain to the people guarding the arrival circle why you're carrying/dragging a resistant/bound/unconscious person through their circle.

Comment: "on the planet" I'm pretty sure you mean plane. Teleportation circle makes a great stargate.

Answer (score 2):

### Imprisonment (minimus containment)

The 9th level spell *[Imprisonment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/imprisonment)* offers a number of different options for confining your foe, but the *minimus containment* version is best suited to your purposes.  On a failed save,

> The target shrinks to a height of 1 inch and is imprisoned inside a gemstone or similar object. Light can pass through the gemstone normally (allowing the target to see out and other creatures to see in), but nothing else can pass through, even by means of teleportation or planar travel.

Since you have now confined your foe inside an easily-transportable object, you can bring them with you when you use your teleport-based effect to get out of the "middle of the wilderness/a sinking ship/the wrong city".

This is similar to the "[put them in a *bag of holding*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/191069/23547)" response, but superior because here:

> The gemstone can't be cut or broken while the spell remains in effect

while for the *bag* it is unclear whether it could [be damaged on the inside](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/191058/how-can-i-teleport-with-an-unwilling-creature#comment514172_191069) by a foe that was not incapacitated.  Further, a conscious opponent inside a *bag* might still have access to its own teleportation magic as a means of escape, but that is specifically prohibited by the *containment* effect.

Other versions of *imprisonment*, such as *burial* or *hedged prison*, remove your foe from the field and potentially could bring them back somewhere else, but [the spell does not specify](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/208845/23547) and such recall would be subject to DM approval.

It may seem extreme to spend a 9th level slot on a spell that still permits a save to avoid capture, but this appears to be about as effective as the other options suggested here.  "**Kill them first**" certainly gives you many options for transport, but depending on your foe getting them to fail a single save might be easier than outright killing them.

***Gate*** is also ninth level and while it does have the advantage of not permitting a save, you still have to force them through it.  Forced movement will likely be achieved through either a failed save or failed contested ability check.

***Teleportation Circle*** is a lower-level, no-save option that you still would still need to force them through.  Further, it has a one minute casting, which gives your foe (and their minions) ten chances to disrupt your concentration or just, you know, leave.

***Transport via Plants*** is an [inventive lower-level option](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/191059/23547) and, as written, does not get a save or explicitly say it can be used only by willing creatures.  Personally, I would interpret "can step into the target plant" to imply willingness, such that your foe can simply choose not to do so, and forced movement would not qualify.

***Dimension Door, Arcane Gate* and *Vortex Warp*** seem too short-distance to meet OP's specifications.

**It does appear that transporting an unwilling but living foe is intended to be restricted to effects of the highest level.**

Answer (score 0):

## Vortex Warp

[Vortex Warp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/vortex-warp) (from Strixhaven: A Curriculum of Chaos) is an interesting choice. It's great for battle control but not perfect for escaping. It's a **Constituion** save which can make it quite challenging, but if you've subdued the baddie/outside of combat you can do it several times (spell slots of course).

Comment: The objective here seems to be to teleport myself and an unwilling target long distances, and *vortex warp* seems to fall short of that, teleporting only the target up to 90 feet. Also, I changed the spell link, we prefer to avoid linking to sites like wikidot that illegally host paid content.

Comment: Thanks for changing the link! I do think this offers useful information because this forum is one of the top results when searching for teleporting an unwilling creature. Vortex Warp is the only direct way to do that, albeit doesn't fit the example scenario provided by OP.